# How to check value existence as hasOwnProperty JSON NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, object

I've found how to check for a key in a JSON object like that :

```
var myJson = {'key':'value', 'key2':'value2'};
if(myJson.hasOwnProperty('key2')){
     //do something if the key exist
}
```

Now, how can i check that value2 exist ? Is something like hasOwnValue exists ?

Comment: You can iterate over properties and check their values

Answer (score 1):

As Molda suggests, there is no way to find out whether an object contains a certain value, other than looping over the fields.

**Pure JS**

```
var myObject = {"a": 1, "b": 2};
var valueImLookingFor = 2;

for (var key in myObject) {
    if (myObject[key] === valueImLookingFor) {
        console.log('Yay, myObject contains', valueImLookingFor);
    }
}
```

There are libraries that do this kind of stuff for you though. Using [Lodash' includes()](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) this becomes really easy:

```
_.includes(myObject, valueImLookingFor); // True
```